# Powershell: how do I use -match to match strictly conditions then send email only when it outputs

Tags: powershell, scripting

So I am trying to filter a text file based on 2 conditions that it must fulfill at the same time.

I would like to check what is the syntax for it to check 2 conditions and both must match.

```
(Get-Content -Path textfile.txt) -match ‘condition1’ -and ‘condition2’ | Set-Content output.txt
```

I tried the code above and also other solutions like select-string but it’s an either or condition instead of strictly matching these 2 conditions

this is my final code

```
$boolean = Get-Content -Path 'C:\test.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match 'condition1' -and $_ -match 'condition2' | Set-Content -Path 'C:\output.txt'
$renamefile = Rename-Item -Path "C:\output.txt" -NewName "server.txt"

If ($boolean)
{ 
Send-MailMessage -From -To -Subject -Body -SmtpServer -Port -Attachement 'C:\output_renamedfile.txt'
echo "email sent"
}
```

Note: for the send-MailMessage parameters I have defined them all accordingly.

Its just that I am sure that it does not go into the if loop because I had put an echo there and it did not echo into the output.
Any advice on this? This script is ran every hour and the file will be renamed as on C:\server.txt but only if it matches condition 1 and condition 2 together.

In the case where it does not match either condition, there will be no email sent, but the file C:\server.txt will still be there, then the next hour will run and if this run matches, it will generate an output.txt and rename it to server.txt (will this replace the existing server.txt and then send the new file - server.txt)?

Comment: FYI: The -match operator takes a regex expression.  Depending on what condition1 and condition2 are, there is a reasonable chance they can be combined into a single regex that does the job.

Comment: Hi Darin thanks a lot, I have edited my final code, would you please take a look and advise at your convenience

Comment: Without knowing what the conditions `conditon1` and `condition2` are,  I don't think I can correctly recreate your situation. And if I can't recreate it, I can't test it or experiment with it.

Comment: Condition1 is a string ‘string1’. Condition2 is another string ‘string 2 2’

Comment: You can experiment with this `$Str = 'this is a test of string 2 2 and also of string1.'; if($Str -match '(?=.*string1)(?=.*string 2 2)') { Write-Host 'Matched!'}`, if it does what you want, then this should work for you `$boolean = Get-Content -Path 'C:\test.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match '(?=.*string1)(?=.*string 2 2)' | Set-Content -Path 'C:\output.txt'`

Comment: Hi Darin it didn’t work as I added a echo check in the if loop it didn’t even go inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

The `-and` operator requires the full expression on each side, so your operation should look like this:

```
(Get-Content -Path textfile.txt) -match ‘condition1’ -and (Get-Content -Path textfile.txt) -match ‘condition2’
```

But the `-match` operator only returns `true` or `false`, so this wouldn't get get you the lines in `textfile.txt` where both conditions match (which I assume is what you want).

To do this, you can use `Where-Object`:

```
Get-Content -Path textfile.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match 'condition1' -and $_ -match 'condition2' }
```

This will return all the lines in `textfile.txt` that match both conditions.

Another option is to use the `Select-String` cmdlet, but since that one doesn't allow you to validate multiple patterns, you'd have to combine the conditions into one pattern using regex, something like this:

```
Get-Content -Path textfile.txt | Select-String -Pattern 'condition1.*condition2'
```

The `Select-String` cmdlet is useful because it returns objects with more properties like `LineNumber`, `Filename`, etc. but if there's a possibility that the order may be reversed or there are other conditions you'd have to factor that into the regex pattern, or use the `Where-Object` method instead.

Comment: Oh yes another question is how can I get this into a loop whereby it will send email only when there’s a new output

Comment: Meaning to say if this line outputs a new text file/replaces existing file then I execute the Send email command

Comment: I'd loop through and use `Compare-Object` to compare the output with an existing value

Comment: Hi there could I edit my code above and take advice from you? I tried a method but it doesn’t go into the if loop went I tested

Comment: Hi there @jeremywat I've edited my final code block, kindly take a look at your free time and convenience if possible ;)